# Nodejs any problem in calling async function without await?

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, async-await

I have an endpoint where I want to do some `async` post processing in which user is not interested in, so I want to process them asynchronously and send send the response the user.

something like this.

```
const createOrder = async (req,res)=>{

  const order = await doCreateOrder(); //creates the order
  somePostProcessing().catch(()=>{
       //handle errors
    });//asycn function which does some db/network operations(not interested in results)
  return reply.send(order)

}
```

But I have a concern that would it cause any issues like memory leak(my team lead says so) and so on?
also what is the best way or other options to do such post processing in nodeJS?

Comment: It's possible, just *usually* not a good idea, though it won't cause performance problems, only possible bugs.

Comment: Do rely on the way `somePostProcessing()` finishes and when? If not, it's fine. But you won't get to handle any possible failures.

Comment: @VLAZ handling error is not a problem I can attach a catch and handle it(updated the question)

Comment: @CertainPerformance so what is the best way to handle it without having a long response time?

Comment: OK, I was talking about the code that didn't have any `.then` or `.catch` attached to it. You *can* attach those instead of using `await`. That would work - the only real reason not to is that it's mixing the Promise API with `await` semantics while *ideally* you want to use one or the other simply in order to be consistent. But there are no real side-effects from mixing the two approaches - `await` is (mostly) syntactic sugar over the Promise API, so `v = await p; console.log(v)` is equal to `p.then(v => console.log(v))`.

Comment: @jfriend00 no it isn't , thanks for pointing it out, I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a problem to ignore the result of a promise.  It's totally optional whether you listen for the successful completion of a promise or not.  There are sometimes reasons to not care.  For example, I often don't make a function wait for the closing of a file at the end of the function.

It is a problem to ignore a rejected promise as that's analogous to an unhandled exception in synchronous code.

So, as long as you are handling all possible errors which it looks like you are with `somePostProcessing().catch(...)`, then it's no problem to ignore the completion.

Note: you do need to make sure your code is anticipating what happens if there's an error in `await doCreateOrder()` as that will immediately reject the promise returned by `createOrder()` so the caller of `createOrder()` needs to have a handler for that rejected promise OR you need a `try/catch` inside this function to catch and handle that possible error.